# tIdentifier Simple array issue

Tags: ruby

I'm working on arrays at the moment. I keep getting hit with a syntax error: the output is saying there's an unexpected tindentifier, which doesn't make sense to me, considering when I worked this on Codeacademy, it came back how I wanted it to. Maybe I'm missing something, but here it is:

```
2d_array= [ ["Yuske", "The protagonist"],["Hiei", "Badmon"],["Kurama", "Smartmon"], ["kuwabara", "dumbmon"], ["Boton", "bae"] ]


2d_array.each do |x,y|

  puts "The character #{x} is regarded as #{y} in the show Yu Yu Hakusho"

end
```

---

Now, when I use this array, it doesn't run. However, when I use the following one, it runs fine:

```
2d_array= [ ["Yuske", "Main Protagonist"],["Hiei", "Badmon"], ["Kuwabara", "Le Idiota"], ["Kurama", "The Quiet Fox"], ["Boton", "Bae"]]
```

---

I've tried to look between the two arrays for any differences, but as far as quotation marks and brackets, it seems fine. I'd appreciate some fresh eyes to see where I'm getting this wrong.

Comment: @Makyen took them off my bad. I didn't think that'd be an issue but you can't just assume that type of stuff. Sorry to anyone who may have been offended. Using that sort of language even as a POC would still offend even your closest friends without you knowing so and has no place on a site where many colors and people of all walks of life come to learn.

Comment: Since I'm probably barred from asking questions hopefully you could ask for me and send a link? I'm trying to learn how to populate both the x and y of an array (i.e [word, definition] using gets.chomp for both. How would I go about doing that? I've searched on here with no luck

Comment: @Mayken take the downvotes off sir. I took the offensive language off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2d_array` is an invalid identifier because it starts with a 2. Variable identifiers must start with lower-case letters or an underscore, _.

I don't know what makes you think the second `2d_array` is working...

Comment: That's weird since it works in the IDE for CodeAcademy. I appreciate it

Comment: Can you A> confirm my answer by clicking on the check mark, and B> provide the URI of this IDE? I assume it's a web page; I want to try it. But I hope you have a real Ruby on your own computer...

Comment: you mind adding some upvotes on to here. I took off the offensive language and the moderator Mayken is no where to be found